Build Failed - Clang invalid version number in '-target arm64-apple-ios10.15-macabi'
I am trying to submit a MacCatalyst app to AppStoreConnect, I have already successfully submitted the iOS app.
However when trying to archive a build for Mac Catalyst 
I get the following error

/appdirectory/clang:1:1 invalid
version number in '-target arm64-apple-ios10.15-macabi'



why's is this happening and how do I resolve the issue?

Based on https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/751573, this looks like an issue with Xcode 15.4
The best option might be to stick with Xcode 15.3 until this gets resolved.
